# Trouble positioning a seekbar below a webview

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to put seekbar below Webview that shows Map.

However when i place the seekbar below WebView in main .xml, it doesn't come up. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/frequency_slider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="1"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"

            android:paddingLeft="4dip"
            android:paddingRight="4dip"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am not able to display seekbar below webview in android app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WebView has height set to "fill_parent" and thus it will take up the whole screen. So your seek bar is getting pushed off the bottom. You have a few options: set the height for your webview to something smaller than "fill_parent" (some static value in dip units, or wrap_content). Or use a RelativeLayout instead of linear and make use of the `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute for the seekbar. And `layout_above="@+id/frequency_slider"` for the WebView. There are other ways you could solve the problem, but those are the easiest two that come to mind for me.